# print a column from Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, echo, mamp

I am trying to print out one column called Language1 from my Table that is called Mull, in a database called v6e.

At the moment i am getting a blank white screen.

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "localhost"; 
$user = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "v6e";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $user, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn)
{
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else

{
$query = "SELECT Language1 FROM Mull WHERE username = 'Mull'";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_arrary($result);
echo $row['Language1'];
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: If you add error checking to your script you will see that you have an undefined function.

Comment: no idea why they're using `session_start();` here Sam @JayBlanchard do you? Oh... that bacon and eggs; sure, that sounds good.

Comment: I have no idea @Fred-ii-, it is just a mess. The guys are hungry, they are leaning towards running to the greasy spoon just up the street.

Comment: *Hmm....* so, I'll take a large fry and don't shake the basket @JayBlanchard the greasier, the better *Sam!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo issue. Change the line:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_arrary($result);
```

With:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Plus, you're also not connecting to DB with your query

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

You should also check for errors:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Thanks. How do i make it display the whole column because at the moment it is only displaying the first line of that column?